# Running Q promises sequentially and pass values to next promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I simplified my problem to easily give an illustration. I would like to implement the function `sequential`:

```
var Q = require('q');

sequential = function(list) {
    last_element = 0;
    results = [];
    list.forEach(function(element) {
        doSomething(element, last_element).then(function (result) {
            results.push(result);
        });
    })
    return results;
}

doSomething = function(element, last_element) {
    var defer = Q.defer();
    some_result_from_api = "this is supposed to be an async operation"
    result = element * last_element * some_result_from_api;
    defer.resolve(result);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Obviously, that loop will not guarantee that `last_element` and `results` will be up to date as another `doSomething` promise runs. Is there an ideal way to do this using q?

Comment: all your `results.push(result);` are executed after `list.forEach` has finished - because asynchrony - replace the forEach with `return list.map(element => doSomething(element, last_element));`

Comment: Not sure what `last_element` has as purpose. It is always 0.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using Q with nodejs unless the node version you are using is seriously old.

Also can't make sense of what it is your code is supposed to do but since you have a list you can either map it to promises and process everything in parallel or reduce the list and process everything in series (one after the other):

```js
sequential = function(list) {
  //in parallel: 
  // return Promise.all(
  //   //last_element is 0 and never changes so I made it 0
  //   list.map(doSomething(element, 0))
  // );
  //serial; one after the other:
  return list.reduce(
    (p,item)=>
      p.then(
        results=>
          //last_element is 0 and never changes so I made it 0
          doSomething(item, 0)
          .then(
            result=>
              results.concat([result])
          )
      ),
      Promise.resolve([])
  );
}

doSomething = async function(element, last_element) {
  const some_result_from_api = await "this is supposed to be an async operation"
  return [element, last_element, some_result_from_api];
}
sequential([1,2,3])
.then(
  results=>
    console.log("Got results:",results)
);
```